# Overwriting javascript function call from Android interface

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-jsinterface

I have a webpage displayed in a WebView. I do not have the control of the webpage. The webpage is executing a javascript and when it's resoving a deffered object it loads an URL. What I want is to capture the `deffered.resolve()` and do something else.

Is there a way to do this through a `@JavascriptInterface` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is capturing the URL loaded by `deffered.resolve` using `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`. This method is called for ajax requests, too.